# What processes affect performance django/ajax

Tags: javascript, django

I have a process in my django application that is painfully slow. It does involve a database write and I have tested it on sqlite and mysql and the results are the same.

I am happy working at the high level of django and javascript, but have no understanding of the underlying interaction of these packages with the os.

The process is complex and I cannot give a minimal working example, but I have timed some parts of the process and I cannot reconcile what is happening.

In my javascript I have the following code

```
function saveMessage(text) {
    if (text) {
        var t0 = performance.now();
        $.ajax(
            {
            type:"GET",
            url: "save-message/"+text,
            cache: false,
            success: function(context) {
                    var t1 = performance.now()
                    console.log("Elapsed " + (t1 - t0) + " msec.")
                    ...
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This process takes on average 2.7 seconds (which is unacceptable)

In my django view I have

```
class SendMessage(View):

@staticmethod
def get(request, text):
    message = Message(request.user.pk, text)
    t1_start = process_time()
    message.save()
    t1_stop = process_time()
    print("save:", t1_stop - t1_start)
    return JsonResponse(context, safe=False)
```

*message* is a django model and is not onerous in its requirements.

This save takes on average 0.038 seconds

However, if I comment out the save, the timing in the javascript function drops to 1.3 seconds.

What is happening here? How can a process that takes a fraction of a second affect the TOTAL time for the process by 1.4 seconds?

The second puzzle is that the print statement in the view function appears in less than a second, but the javascript log does not appear until more than a second later. Why the lag? Surely, the process has been handed over to the template (and javascript) so what is going on?

I am hoping that some understanding of the issues will help me to improve the overall performance.

Comment: I'd begin by using the browser's network-monitor features to watch the JSON request going out and then coming back.  Also: I don't see *anything* in your code snippet which ought to be responsible for "anything more than a few milliseconds."  There's something **else** going on here that you haven't seen yet, and I doubt that you have presented it here.  **"Nothing** should take 'whole seconds!'"

Comment: "Nothing should take 'whole seconds! - I agree - just trying to get a handle on it

Comment: I have not found out what causes this, but I have rewritten the code to save and retrieve Messages from file. I have got back my sub-second response, so I must have been having a problem with the django read/write model.